# Cannot make background image from within the file to display on dive in TailwindCSS

Tags: css, url, background-image, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am trying to display a specific background image on a div in style or class by using Tailwind CSS but the image in not appearing. I cannot put it as a image since i want it to repeat throughout the div.
`

```
<div style="background-image: url('/wave.svg');" class="block bg-repeat-x bg-contain bg-center" >
**code**
</div>
```

`

I have tried to put the url as "../public.wave.svg" but the terminal outputs:

*files in the public directory are served at the root path.
Instead of /public/wave.svg, use /wave.svg.*

I have also tried it within a class in the div but cannot seem to find the problem to why my image is not showing up. When i put it as a img src it appears but i cannot manipulate it like that.

Comment: Did you try "//wave.svg " ?

Comment: yes, but still it doesn't show up

Comment: Does your block has some height? It may be loaded but invisible because block has no [height](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jhZMdtpLWd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to find here that simple real problem...

first go tailwind 'output.css' and add here a standart css class like '.addtest{}' with include your background.svg !

add it to your div, and is it works ?
is it don't work ? (find your real problem..)

ok, is it solved for standart css ?

now go and and take that css to your inner tailwind css or direct inline-css to html with 'style'.

are you try "./folder/image.svg"

not "../folder/image.svg"

not "/folder/image.svg"